# Division Algorithms

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am brand new to number theory and reading "The Queen of Mathematics" by J. Goldman, for a basic understanding of its origins and concepts. Hopefully my questions aren't too fuzzy and the intent is clear:

(1) Why is it Euclid notates integer division in the manner of p. 6? Specifically, it doesn't make sense to me why the integers are expressed in terms of multiples and remainders of each other?

(2) The Euclid algorithm follows for common divisors but it to seems very abstract - probably because I am unclear on the notation in (1).

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The notion Euclid introduced (and further developed by Gauss) is a very powerful way to  represent numbers and classify them together based on their remainders as it is very helpful to study the behaviors of small numbers and apply them to bigger numbers.

Comment: Thanks, @TheDemonix_Hermit. It seems this new way of thinking will take longer to absorb than anticipated.

Comment: @GeoffreyTurner No problem . Just keep in mind that every big thing is composed of smaller stuffs , so to understand the bigger thing , we only to have to understand the smaller things they are made of :)

Comment: We don't all have a copy of this book. Could you please make your question more self-contained?